# XCTest: Use of unresolved identifier XCTContext

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, xctest

I'm using Xcode Version 8.3.3 and I'm trying to XCTContext on Swift but I'm getting the following error:

```
Use of unresolved identifer XCTContext
```

This is implementation:

```
   XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Capture screenshot") { activity in
    let screen = XCUIScreen.main
    let screenShot = screen.screenshot()
    let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenShot)
    attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
    activity.add(attachment)
    }
```

[image]

XCTContext doesn't event show in autocomplete:

[image]

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Did you import the XCTest framework?

Comment: @the4kman Yes, import XCTest.

Comment: I see it is available from Xcode 9.0 and up, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctcontext/2903482-runactivity

Comment: @Breek, I understand and as you can see in the image I add to my post it doesn't event show in autocomplet

Comment: are you in an XCUITest target? context won't work in unit test target

Comment: @AquilaSagitta, of course I'm in the XCUITest. I created a new project and still have the same issue

Comment: @breek is correct. XCTContext isn't available in xcode 8

Comment: @user2924482, just want to let u know I have both Xcode 8.3.3 and 9.0 in my machine, I can see `XCTContext` in 9.0 but not 8.3.3. Never use `XCTContext` before and it makes me feel like it is not available in Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 2):

XCTContext is only available with Xcode 9. That's why you get this error when trying to use it with Xcode 8.x

Comment: Make sure you are using Xcode 9 or above than any other version. XCTContent is available only with xcode9 and above